# PHP preg_match_all - Get what is inside pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a lot of difficulties in this REGEX stuff, can any one help improve my code? 
Thank you in advanced.

What I need is to get the content in side the [Slide] CONTENT [/Slide] tags. 
What i am doing is:

```
preg_match ('/\[Slide\].*\[\/Slide\]/s', $content, $matches);
$conteudo_slide = $matches[0];

$conteudo_full = preg_replace('/\[Slide\]/s', "", $conteudo_slide);
$conteudo_full = preg_replace('/\[\/Slide\]/s', "", $conteudo_full);
```

the content of the page is:

```
<p>[Slide]http://www.gprco-cpa.com/images/industries/corporations.jpg[/Slide]</p>
<p>[Slide]http://www.expatcpa.com/Corporation_HQ.jpg[/Slide]</p>
<p><br />[Slide]</p>
<p><a href="http://localhost/~tiago/main_wordpress/?attachment_id=437" rel="attachment wp-att-437">
<img class="alignright size-full wp-image-437" title="lightbulb"src="http://localhost/~tiago/main_wordpress/wpcontent/uploads/2012/09/lightbulb1.jpg" alt="" width="500" height="334" /></a>[/Slide]</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>[Slide]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHVOyGVQ3Tw&amp;feature=g-all-u[/Slide]</p>
```

Isn´t any more correct way of doing this? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding `()`:

```
preg_match ('/\[Slide\](.*?)\[\/Slide\]/s', $content, $matches);
```

Comment: <p>[Slide]http://www.gprco-cpa.com/images/industries/corporations.jpg[/Slide]</p>
<p>[Slide]http://www.expatcpa.com/Corporation_HQ.jpg[/Slide]</p>
<p><br />[Slide]</p>
<p><a href="http://localhost/~tiago/main_wordpress/?attachment_id=437" rel="attachment wp-att-437"><img class="alignright size-full wp-image-437" title="lightbulb" src="http://localhost/~tiago/main_wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/lightbulb1.jpg" alt="" width="500" height="334" /></a>[/Slide]</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>[Slide]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHVOyGVQ3Tw&amp;feature=g-all-u[/Slide]</p>

Comment: preg_match ('/\[Slide\](.*?)\[\/Slide\]/s', $content, $matches);

WORKED!! Thank you very much!